# UTC Date Time not matching between two machines

Tags: javascript, python, date, datetime, utc

I have two projects, one written in JS and another in Python. I have a functionality that requires to calculate the current UTC time difference coming from both projects. When I test the current UTC time I notice there is always the exact difference, and I'm expecting it to be almost equal.

The time difference calculation is done in the JS project. Using a websocket, I'm getting the UTC time from the Python project and subtract `Math.round(new Date().getTime())` from it. The difference is almost always the same, but also unacceptable.

This is how I'm getting the UTC time from Python:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
time = time.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
time = time.timestamp()
```

I'm running the JS project on my windows WSL environment. When I run the python project from a local (WSL) docker container I get a difference of 7.02 seconds. When instead I run the python project from an LXC container on my raspberry pi, I'm getting around 3.04 seconds.

I need to have this difference equal down to the second. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Did you check the system times of both environments individually? A discrepancy like that sounds like the time is off somewhere, as opposed to a transmission delay.

Comment: FWIW, that `time.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` is perfectly superfluous; but it shouldn't have any effect…

Comment: Hi @ChrisG. The system time is in fact different. On Docker it is UTC and on my WSL, where I have JS running it is CEST. I am assuming that since I'm using UTC time, I'm getting a universal time independent from the system's time. Is this correct?

Comment: @deceze, Thanks! I'll check on that. But yeah I don't think it makes an effect since the difference is quite minimal still.


Edit: Yep no effect, but cleaner! Thanks!

Comment: The configured *timezone* on the two systems should be irrelevant, as you note. The important thing is, are their *clocks* apart by ~7 seconds or not?

Comment: So the 7 second difference test, is having both projects running on the same environment, but Python is containerized in docker. I need to be sure and safely assume that whichever machine runs JS, matches the time it gets from the websocket. If not .. I need to implement some dirty workaround which is not desired.

Comment: I'm not talking about timezones, I'm talking about the seconds on the system clocks. I don't see how containers would cause a 7 second delay, plus: is one clock 7 seconds behind, or are they both a few seconds off? I mean: if it's 9AM sharp, does the Python system show 9:00:00? Or 8:59:53? Or 9:00:07? Same for the JS system. Until you have answered this, doing anything else is pointless.

Comment: Re `Math.round(new Date().getTime())`. *getTime* returns an integer so *Math.round* is redundant. `new Date().getTime()` returns exactly the same value as `Date.now()`, but the latter is more efficient as it doesn't create a Date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using ntpdate

I have installed this package `apt install ntpdate` and ran `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org`. What this command does it to sync your system's clock. I did this on both of my systems and I had no issues with mismatch utc timestamp.

Of course I wonder if, when JS is ran on and android device, would that system be syncronized too? I'm assuming yes for now :)

Comment: If you install an ntp client on your server to ensure that the server has an accurate clock, that does *not* impact the client. An Android device has a completely separate clock and may still drift independently of your server.

Comment: Yes I get that, but also I can have no control over the Android device and synchronize it's time. AFAIK this is the best I could do to configure the setup, without applying dirty fixes. I wasn't in favor of getting the server's clock from my android device, and calculate the offset for my other timing calculations

Comment: Indeed, you should try not to use any client-side time at all for anything important. If you do, you would basically need to send the server's time to the client and then always do special calculations, which is also annoying and not entirely correct either.